# Insert HTML, CSS and JavaScript in a block

Tags: episerver

Is it possible to inject a HTML, CSS and JavaScript into a block in EPIServer?

I tried to add some HTML and it disappear after saving.

I do not have development access to the CMS but only as a Editor.

Answer (score 1):

In the case a developer have implemented and configured `TinyMCEPluginNonVisual` it would be possible. Otherwise no.

[Allow custom HTML attributes in TinyMCE in EPiServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390552/allow-custom-html-attributes-in-tinymce-in-episerver)

Comment: I agree, although in most cases I prefer adding it through Google Tag Manager or equivalent (even though changes aren't included in the Episerver version history for the content). Script tags in HTML properties are easily removed accidentally by other web editors in WYSIWYG mode. :)